# VS2015: using /Wall from the CLI but disabling warning in some file (eg: thoses in Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, compiler-warnings

I wanted to enable the `/Wall` option using the Command line and IncrediBuild, but now I have too many warning from files that are mostly "read only":

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath(35): warning C4514: 'abs': unreferenced inline function has been removed
```

I don't/won't touch *cmath* but still I've got those picky warning (which I asked).

Is there a way to tell VS2015 to ignore warning in certain directories? (like if I were using a *pragma* inside those file to locally disable such warning).

**Note:** it was perhaps not clear, but I don't want to use a trick such as modifying local source (that's a big project with at least 1000 cpp files) or system header. Only through the command line.

Comment: Use a pch with all windows header files and disable all warnings using pragma push pop?

Comment: /Wall is not very useful for the MSVC++ compiler.  You get *everything*, even rather irrelevant diagnostics like this one.  Neither its own #include files nor the SDK headers are /Wall clean.  You'd have to add a big list of /wd to turn them off again.  /W4 is the smart choice.

Comment: I'll try that ASAP, but still, I feel like I will have misleading warning from readonly headers.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is wrap all the system includes with `#pragma warning push / pop`. I have convenience macros for that in [my library](https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cpputils#compilercompiler_warnings_controlh).

Usage example:

```
#include "compiler/compiler_warnings_control.h"

// The following header files belong to a 3rd-party library.
// These headers produce various compiler warnings.
// So I simply wrap them in warning suppression macros:

DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNINGS
#include "libusb.h"
#include "zlib.h"
RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNINGS
```

Implementation (MSVC part only; the complete implementation in my repo is cross-platform):

```
#define COMPILER_PRAGMA(text) __pragma(text)
#define STORE_COMPILER_WARNINGS COMPILER_PRAGMA(warning(push))
#define RESTORE_COMPILER_WARNINGS COMPILER_PRAGMA(warning(pop))
#define DISABLE_SPECIFIC_COMPILER_WARNING(warningCode) COMPILER_PRAGMA(warning (diable: warningCode))

#define DISABLE_COMPILER_WARNINGS COMPILER_PRAGMA(warning(push, 0)) // Set /W0
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. The answer would be good if that was not an already existing project with too many file for such solution to be possible. The idea is however nice.